# Pressing <Alt-3> (left alt key) suddenly maps to Esc (and not the character "#") using iTerm2

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, macos, escape

Characteristics:

MacOS 10.14.6

I'm using VIM as text editor for a few weeks, with both `Terminal` and `iTerm2`

I could write character dependent on hitting key <kbd>alt</kbd> (left alt key in `iTerm`) without problem

Ex:

- <kbd>alt-3</kbd> gave the the character "#"
- <kbd>alt-5</kbd> gave the the character "["
- <kbd>alt-6</kbd> gave the the character "]"

But suddenly, it changed and now when hit those shortcuts, it does not write the corresponding character with the left alt key and quits insert mode instead (although the command with the desired output work with the right alt key in `iTerm2`. Moreover combinations with both right and left alt key are also working fine in `Terminal`). I think that this change came after `Vim` or `iTerm2` asked me if I wanted to change some shortcuts and I (stupidly) responded yes.

So i conclude that pressing  suddenly seems to map to the command `Esc` (and not the character "#", How do I change that mapping

I tried the following command  without success:

```
:unmap <Alt-3>
:unmap <Alt-3> Esc
:unmap <press Alt-3>
:unmap <press Alt-3> Esc

:map  <A-3> #
:map! <A-3> #
:map  <A-"> #
:map! <A-"> #
:set timeout timeoutlen=5000 ttimeoutlen=250
```

I want be able to write the character "#" with the shortcut <kbd>Alt-3</kbd> (left alt button) in `iTerm2`

Did I change something by mistake? What should I do to fix the problem? Should I change the `~/vimrc` file

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Vi/Vim SE. Have you read the help docs? (Enter `:h :map`). If you're trying both `map` and `map!` it seems that you're not even sure what mode you want to do the mapping in. Similar comment regarding `press`. It will be easier to help you if you familiarize yourself with that documentation.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with Vim, more likely an iTerm configuration. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196357/9447571) about handling of the Meta key, although in your case using ,`ESC+` is probably what's *causing* your problem, so you might want to switch to one of the other settings, see if that fixes it...

Comment: Many thanks @filbranden! That posted helped a lot. I could solve the problem be going to Iterm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Keys and there setting "Left Option (alt) Key from "Esc+" to "Normal"

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! We do generally discourage cross-posting on the stack-exchange network, to keep closer to a « single source of truth » model

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/q/57649240/9447571